# StoreKit's SKStoreProductViewController leaving space between the nav bar and the view?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, storekit

I have this subclass of UIViewController that shows a `SKStoreProductViewController`.  This view controller was originally created for iOS 5 and is NOT using auto-layout. 
My problem is that when the `SKStoreProductViewController` is presented, there's a space between the nav bar and the actual content... if you scroll the view, the segmented control (Details/Reviews/Related) floats below the nav bar (see the images below, I added a mask to the images to make the problem more apparent).

Since we don't have access to the presented view controller I'm guessing it has to do with the controller that presents the `SKStoreProductViewController`.  When the user taps on the button that presents the controller I've tried to change/shift the frame of the view, I've also done something like `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;` but nothing seems to help.

Has anyone have had a similar problem? Any ideas on how to fix it?

[image: Showing space between navigation bar and view]
[image: Showing the segmented control bar floating]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there's a bug on the `UIAppearance` protocol on iOS 7.  I found people having (*other*) problems when using `UIAppearance`.
I was using something like:

`[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`

which works on iOS 5, but for iOS 6+ I set the background image directly on the navigation bar:

`[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`

It looks like a small difference, but it fixed my problem.

Comment: who's navigation controller are you calling this on? Are you putting the SKSPVC inside a nav controller and setting it there? or on the presenting view controller's nav?

Comment: I set the `SKStoreProductViewController` on a subclass of `UIViewController`, but I don't think that matters.  You can create it on the AppDelegate and you'd have the same output.