# SKStoreProductViewController not working on iPad iOS 8

Tags: ipad, ios8, storekit

I'm using SKStoreProductViewController on iPad with iOS 8. Pressing a button opens an instance of it:

```
[self.storeProductViewController loadProductWithParameters:@{SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier:appStoreIdNumber}
                completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error) {...}];
[[self getPresentingViewController] presentViewController:self.storeProductViewController animated:YES completion:^{...}];
```

It pops up the first time fine. But after it is dismissed, pressing the button again to reopen it throws an exception and the pop up never appears.

```
<SKRemoteProductViewController: 0x15c1ec00> timed out waiting for fence barrier from com.apple.ios.StoreKitUIService
```

Anyone know what's going on or how to work around it?

Answer (score 0):

I've also had some other problems with UIAppearance and StoreKit not working together (see [StoreKit's SKStoreProductViewController leaving space between the nav bar and the view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617937/storekits-skstoreproductviewcontroller-leaving-space-between-the-nav-bar-and-th))

I was having the same problem that you now have and removing all UIAppearance code fixed it, but I noticed that the SKStoreProductViewController won't load any iPad apps on an iPhone on iOS 8 and it will fail silently.  Let me know if you have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, where the first time I present the SKRemoteProductViewController it works fine, but subsequent presentations give the error as the OP described. Apparently the problem is related to presenting the same SKRemoteProductViewController more than once. If I dispose of the SKRemoteProductViewController after presenting it and then re-load another one each time I want it to present again then things work without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem as well. Make sure that `identifier` is actually an `NSString`

```
@{ SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier : identifier }
```

I was inadvertently passing an `NSURL` object, which resulted in the same error -- "timed out waiting for fence barrier from com.apple.ios.StoreKitUIService"

Answer (score 0):

you should present SKStoreProductViewController before loading it